# Trying to get InetAddress.getLocalHost.getHostAddress (Java/Scala) to return external IP

Tags: java, scala, networking, localhost, akka

So I'm having a problem with using `InetAddress.getLocalHost.getHostAddress` to get the external IP address of a given machine.

I'm actually doing this in Scala in a sense - the configuration file for Akka Remote Actors default uses `InetAddress.getLocalHost.getHostAddress` to get the IP address of the machine, which is what I want since I will be deploying the actors on several machines. However, it seems to be returning `127.0.0.1` instead of the external IP address I want (since the remote actors need to communicate back and forth across the netwrok).

The problem is that I can't use any of the methods I've found on Google to circumvent this since they all seem to involve adjusting the code itself, whereas here I don't really have any code to adjust, the DSL just automatically uses `InetAddress.getLocalHost.getHostAddress`.

I've read on a few threads from a Google search that you can circumvent this by editing your host file or something? How do I do this?

Thanks!
-kstruct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to use [NetworkInterface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html) class.

In particular, use static [getNetworkInterfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html#getNetworkInterfaces%28%29) method to enumerate all available network interfaces.

Comment: I don't think I can do that - there is no code to modify. It is just the way the Akka Remote Actor configuration file works - if a hostname is not specified, it uses `InetAddress.getLocalHost.getHostAddress`, I am never using that myself. http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0/general/configuration.html

Comment: @kstruct. Are you running with security manager?  Documentation for getLocalHost says that if you don't have correct permissions the method always returns loopback address.

Comment: Hm.. I'm not too familiar with the JVM right now, could you explain to me how I would determine if I was running with this "security manager?" I definitely do not have root access on the remote machines, if that's relevant.

Comment: @kstruct. Get the command line that started your java application (ProcessExplorer on Windows, ps on Linux) and check if you see this `java.security.manager` somewhere on the command line.

Comment: Nope, only Java-related thing I see is `java -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -Xms1536m -Xmx1536m -XX:MaxPermSize=384m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=192m -Dfile.encoding=UTF8`

Answer (score 2):

Check your /etc/hosts file. It should map 'localhost' to 127.0.0.1 and your real hostname to your real IP address, or one of them :-| Some Linux distributions get this wrong apparently.

Comment: @yanghaogn I do *not* regard removing information as 'making it more clear'. Edit rejected.

Answer (score 0):

i got a partial solution if getLocalHost doesn't works.
this solution have the problem that you must to know the name of your network interface in order to match the real one. Maybe you can improve this code removing "virtual" devices and something else.

This is scala code, but java code is very similar

```
  def returnInterfaceAddress() : InetAddress = {
    var myInetAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost
    val interfaces : util.Enumeration[NetworkInterface] = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()
    while(interfaces.hasMoreElements){
      val inter = interfaces.nextElement()
      if(inter.getDisplayName() == "Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller"){
        myInetAddress = inter.getInetAddresses().nextElement()
      }
    }
    myInetAddress
  }
```